# Trigger Socket on a Post request

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Trying to emit a message on a POST request, getting an error saying Cannot read property `emit` of undefined

```
app.post('/webhook/orders/updated', function(req, res, next) {
    io.socket.emit('order', "Order Id " + req.body.data.id + " : Updated");
});
```

In the index.js, I have the following code:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

On the UI, I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('order', function(msg) {
         $('#status').append($('<li class="alert alert-info">').text(msg));
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select a socket to emit.

To do that, i think you need on each connection, to pass the socket id to the client side like this :

**Server Side**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.emit('connection:sid', socket.id);
});
```

**Client Side**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('connection:sid', function(socketId) {
         // Set socketId to your cookies, or global variable
      });
   });
</script>
```

And then, you have to send your socketId to each GET or POST request you do, has header or param.
Finally, you can access to your correct socket on your route:

**ROUTE**

```
app.post('/webhook/orders/updated', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.socketId) {
       var socket = io.sockets.connected[req.body.socketId]; // Find socket by id
       if (socket) {
          socket.emit('order', "Order Id " + req.body.data.id + " : Updated");
       }
       else {
          // No socket found with socketId
       }
    }
    else {
       // No socketId received
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice solution here

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution. I replaced `io.socket` to `io.sockets`

```
app.post('/webhook/orders/updated', function(req, res, next) {
    io.sockets.emit('order', "Order Id " + req.body.data.id + " : Updated");
});
```

Comment: With that solution, you emit to all connected sockets, and not just one :)

Comment: Agreed..!! :) .