# Emit socket on post request

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I`m trying to create emit for the socket on post request from postman but got some troubles. I found an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47943549/trigger-socket-on-a-post-request) but it seems not working for me. I have this code in my app.js

#### App.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const eventsRoute = require('./routes/eventsRoute')

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {origin: "*"},
    path: '/api/events'
})
io.of('/api/events/').on('connection', socket => console.log('connected'))
...
app.use('/api/events', eventsRoute(io))
module.exports = app
```

And here I got eventsRoute.js code. Here, I think, is the main problem

#### eventsRoute.js

```
const express = require('express')
const errorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler')
const router = express.Router()

const returnRouter = io => {
    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            io.sockets.emit('create', req.body)
            res.status(200).json({message: 'successful'})
        } catch (e) {
            errorHandler(e)
        }
    })

    router.get("/", function (req, res) {
        try {
            res.send({})
        } catch (e) {
            errorHandler(e)
        }
    })

    return router
}


module.exports = returnRouter
```

And on my client side, I have some code in the script tag. Here it is

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io('ws://localhost:5000', {path: '/api/events'})
     socket.on('create', data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I could make it work with some changes: 1 - I didn't use `path` in the server options, 2 - I used `ws://localhost:5000/api/events` and removed the options in the client, 3 - instead of listen in the `create` event (that never fires), I've listened on `socket.on('connect')` -> [screenshot example](https://i.imgur.com/WgifVfq.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, the main reason was in ... all files. Let's begin with **index.js**. I'm exporting the app. Instead of that, I have to export `http`. Then in **app.js**, I will have to change line with sockets to this

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http, options)
io.of('/api/events')
    .on('connection', socket => {
        app.use('/api/events', eventsRoute(socket))
    })
```